# mysql getting max min values across multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a price range for some products from two tables.

Table1 (products):

```
pid | products_name | products_model
1   | Product 1.....| model 1
2   | Product 2.....| model 2
```

Table2 (products_prices):

```
pid | nerchant_id   | price | sale_price | sale_start_date | sale_expire_date
1   | RVTBV         | 11.90 | 0          | NULL            | NULL
1   | QNUNU         | 11.90 | 9.90       | 2013-05-01      | 2013-12-31
1   | YOLOR         | 12.90 | 10.90      | 2013-04-01      | 2013-12-31
2   | RVTBV         | 20.90 | 0          | NULL            | NULL
2   | QNUNU         | 29.90 | 25.90      | 2013-04-01      | 2013-12-31
2   | YOLOR         | 29.90 | 0          | NULL            | NULL
```

How do I get a result with price range to look like this:

```
pid | products_name | products_model | min_price | max_price
1   | Product 1.... | model 1 ...... | 10.90 ... | 12.90
2   | Product 2.... | model 2 ...... | 20.90 ... | 29.90
```

I am using a main query to get products data from table1 then a loop with php foreach product to get the min max values depending on sale start and expiry dates.

It does the work but I don't like subqueries with php. I prefer one MySQL query for performance reasons.

Thanks for helping.

Until now the following statement the best

```
SELECT      p.pid,

                p.manufacturers_id,

                p.products_image,

        p.products_name,

                (select min(if(CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN pp.sale_start_date AND pp.sale_expire_date and pp.sale_price>'0', pp.sale_price, pp.price)) from products_prices pp where p.pid = pid) as min_price,

                (select max(if(CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN pp.sale_start_date AND pp.sale_expire_date and pp.products_sale_price>'0', pp.sale_price, pp.price)) from products_prices pp where p.pid = pp.pid) as max_price

                       FROM products p

                       WHERE p.products_status = '1'

                       AND p.categories_id = '1'

                       ORDER BY min_price ASC  LIMIT 0, 100
```

is it possible to optimize it a little bit?

Resumé:

sometimes is the solution so simple that i don´t see it;)

ok the project is an price comparison plattform. Products will be updated hourly or something like that, but not all prices will change. So let´s say 10% will be updated.
But the data must be retrieverd with each visit of the website.

In this case it will be more reads than writes (80-20).

I can add two extra columns to the products table (min_price and max_price) that i update only once if price_data changes.

on one Hand the update will be a little bit more complicated but that´s not a drama. On the other hand the data will be retrieved very fast.

I have testet 3 options based on 15000 products to retrieve 100 rows:
worst: the group by approch (over 1 sec)
good: the approach of arheops (0,12 sec)
best: update once with two extra colums (0,07 sec)

I go with the third option.

thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Why is the min price 10.90 instead of 9.90?

Comment: @Strawberry, its because the OP wants to get the price details where the `price` column is `max` for a particular product

Comment: @ahajji06 please chk my updated answer and let us know if it solves your problem

Comment: @Akash You may be right, but unless you have a direct line to the OP, I cannot see how you could know that.

Comment: And sale_price should be NULL, not 0.00, when there is no sale. (In fact sale data should probably be in a different table altogether)

Comment: @Strawberry :), I agree it should have been made clear by the OP (this is what I assume)

Comment: @strawberry it will be complicated for no reasons if i use an extra table for sale_prices. I have to retrieve my data from 3 tables.

Comment: @ahajji06 I'm afraid you're mistaken. It won't be significantly more complicated. And there is a sound reason for doing so. But, hey, you're the DBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depend of you query.

If you query only some values from product, this will be optimal:

```
select pid,products_name,products_model,
   (select min(price) from price where price.pid=product.pid) as min_price,
   (select max(price) from price where price.pid=product.pid) as max_price
 from product  where some_filter_here;
```

If you need got FULL table, this one is best:

```
select a.pid,products_name,products_model,min_price,max_price 
     from product as a 
 left join ( 
   select pid,min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price 
        from price group by pid
           ) as b on b.pid=a.pid
```

Comment: until now is your first approach the best if i expand it with an if statement.
It took 0.1221 sec to run for 100 products from 15000 rows and each one with four prices.

Comment: You need have index on pid in price table. Also increase of sort buffer can help

Comment: So speed is more important than accuracy? That makes no sense. Anyway, as long you're happy, I'm happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for your requirements.

**Update:**
The first query now also considers the `start/end date` for the sale price

```
SELECT
  p.pid,
  p.products_name,
  p.products_model,
  pp.price as min_price,
  pp.sale_price as max_price
FROM
  products p
  JOIN products_prices pp ON ( p.pid = pp.pid )
  LEFT JOIN products_prices pp2 ON ( pp2.pid = pp.pid AND pp2.price > pp.price AND pp.sale_start_date BETWEEN pp2.sale_start_date AND pp2.sale_expire_date )
WHERE
  pp2.pid IS NULL AND NOW() BETWEEN pp.sale_start_date and pp.sale_expire_date
```

The below one, gets the `max`, `min` of the `prices` avaliable for a product

```
SELECT
  p.pid,
  p.products_name,
  p.products_model,
  MIN( LEAST( pp.price, pp.sale_price) ) as min_price,
  MAX( GREATEST( pp.price, pp.sale_price) ) as max_price
FROM
  products p
  JOIN products_prices pp ON ( p.pid = pp.pid )
WHERE
  pp.sale_price <> 0
GROUP BY
  p.pid
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bfa2/27)

Comment: It´s right The price shouldn´t be equal zero but i have to check if the the sale price is active now() between sale_start_date and sale_expire_date.
Your Query took over one second, its to long for me.

Comment: @ahajji06 yes, the reason why its slow is because you could be having large number of records and you are just interested the one that falls between the `now()` and `start_date` 'end_date`

Comment: @ahajji06 I have updated the first query with the `date` condition

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT   products.*,
         MIN(IF(CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN sale_start_date AND sale_expire_date, sale_price, price)) min_price,
         MAX(price) max_price
FROM     products JOIN products_prices USING (pid)
GROUP BY pid
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a485e/1).

Comment: the if statement is right and it should be used for teh max price too but i won´t use group by beacuse if i run explain it shows using temporary und that´s why it takes long time.

Comment: @ahajji06: If you use `IF()` for the `max_price`, you will get different results to those shown in your question (as, for `pid=1`, the sale price of `10.90` will be used instead of the shown `12.90`, which causes a max of `11.90` to be returned).  `GROUP BY` in and of itself need not be slow; you probably just need to create appropriate indexes.

Comment: i am already using it from the start and i get the rigt prices beacause even if the product is on sale it might be also the most expencive one

Answer (score 0):

I think you're actually after this. I've amended sale_price to NULL in the event that there is no sale which is just as it should be if you're going to insist on including sale information in the products_prices table...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;
 CREATE TABLE products
 (pid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,products_name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,products_model VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO products VALUES 
 (1   ,'Product 1','model 1'),
 (2   ,'Product 2','model 2');

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products_prices;
 CREATE TABLE products_prices
 (pid INT NOT NULL
 ,merchant_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL
 ,price DECIMAL(5,2)NOT NULL
 ,sale_price DECIMAL(5,2) NULL
 ,sale_start_date DATE
 ,sale_expire_date DATE
 ,PRIMARY KEY(pid,merchant_id)
 );

 INSERT INTO products_prices VALUES
 (1,'RVTBV',11.90,NULL,NULL,NULL),
 (1,'QNUNU',11.90,9.90,'2013-05-01','2013-12-31'),
 (1,'YOLOR',12.90,10.90,'2013-04-01','2013-12-31'),
 (2,'RVTBV',20.90,NULL,NULL,NULL),
 (2,'QNUNU',29.90,25.90,'2013-04-01','2013-12-31'),
 (2,'YOLOR',29.90,NULL,NULL,NULL);

 SELECT p.* 
      , MIN(CASE WHEN CURDATE() BETWEEN sale_start_date AND sale_expire_date THEN pp.sale_price ELSE pp.price END) min_price 
      , MAX(CASE WHEN CURDATE() BETWEEN sale_start_date AND sale_expire_date THEN pp.sale_price ELSE pp.price END) max_price 
   FROM products p 
   JOIN products_prices pp 
     ON pp.pid = p.pid 
  GROUP 
     BY p.pid;

+-----+---------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
| pid | products_name | products_model | min_price | max_price |
+-----+---------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
|   1 | Product 1     | model 1        |     10.90 |     11.90 |
|   2 | Product 2     | model 2        |     20.90 |     29.90 |
+-----+---------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: i will never use group by except i have no choice, i would prefer to rewrite an application than to use it (the time spent to retrieve the data is more than the double). And yes there are many reasons to store the special_price data in a seperate table but i don´t need it in this case.

Comment: This comment/criticism makes no sense. If performance is at issue then appropriate indexes are required, not erroneous queries.